# Unreal Engine: Accessing blueprint instance data of dynamically spawned actor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have a C++ class with an exposed `UPROPERTY` which is extended via a blueprint class. I used the blueprint to set the value of the property.

Now what I want to do is spawn an Actor from this blueprint class and have my C++ code work with the property that was set in the blueprint. All works well if I drag an instance of the blueprint class into the world from the unreal editor. However, if I dynamically spawn this actor of the same blueprint class from my default `GameMode` class, I can see that an instance of that class has been added into the world (I see it in the World Outliner) but when the C++ code runs, the values that were set from the blueprint are not there.

Why does spawning the blueprint class differently (one method by dragging it into the world from the editor, the other method by spawning it from the GameMode class) lead to different results? Why am I unable to access the blueprint data if the actor is spawned from the `GameMode` class?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're spawning an instance of the derived **Blueprint class** and not the parent C++ class from GameMode?

Also check that when you're trying to access the member variable, that you're casting the instance to the **Blueprint class** and not the C++ class.

If you're not already doing it, it might be a good idea to append `_BP` or something similar to all Blueprint derived classes to ensure you always know which version you're dealing with.

Comment: Please let me know if this helped. Also mark the question as answered if so.